# Why do frogs and toads only appear when it is dark outside?

Tags: zoology

I noticed outdoors how frogs and toads only appear when it is dark or cloudy. Such as only after it rains or during night time. Why is this?

Comment: The premise is false.  Frogs and toads don't only appear when it's cloudy (personal observation, easily repeated in most rural areas).  Most amphibians prefer cool, humid environments, as their moist skin serves as a secondary respiratory organ: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amphibian#Skin

Comment: I understand.. Do you think I should I reword my question?

Comment: I think it needs to be almost a completely different question, something like "why do amphibians prefer humid environments?".  Because at least in temperate areas, any small pond is likely to have frogs &c active during the day.  For instance, there's a medium-sized pond near me where during the season when tadpoles become frogs, you can hardly walk along the edge without stepping on small ones - and this is on the edge of the semi-desert Great Basin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see them,( or their ripples after they jump into the water ) during the day; I have 2 small ponds in the yard. I see tree frogs in my patio plants during the day but they are sleeping. The frogs/toads certainly make more noise when it rains ,has rained, or is going to rain. even during the day. They are certainly more active at night . I expect more bugs around then . I only see the geckos at night ,near the lights.

Comment: This sounds nice . maybe they need to conserve their energy during the day . maybe they are attracted to the water in your ponds!

Comment: Yes, the pond are a big draw. The neighborhood is very quiet at night , except within a hundred yards of the ponds. People on the phone have asked my wife the noise in the background. My son made the frog noise the ring tone for his phone.